# Нейросетевая экспертная система для диагностики двигателя внутреннего сгорания автомобиля на c#

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети

Существуют ли на сегодняшний день экспертные системы основанные на искусственных нейронных сетях для диагностики двигателей внутреннего сгорания автомобиля? Можно ли такую экспертную систему реализовать на языке C#?

Comment: Не вижу. почему было бы нельзя реализовать. Тьюринг-полный язык всё-таки.

Comment: Для разработки экспертных систем на C# можно использовать [Clips для .NET](https://clips.codeplex.com/). Там и простая демка для диагностики автомобиля есть :) Вот по поводу искусственных нейронных сетей не знаю.